# Spark: Use Persistent Table as Streaming Source for Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I stored data in a table:

```
spark.table("default.student").show()

(1) Spark Jobs
+---+----+---+
| id|name|age|
+---+----+---+
|  1| bob| 34|
+---+----+---+
```

I would like to make a read stream using that table as source. I tried

```
newDF=spark.read.table("default.student")
newDF.isStreaming
```

Which returns `False`.

Is there a way to use a table as Streaming Source?

Comment: You can create a web socket and send the data to it. To fetch the data from the table you can add an arbitrary time column and query the table for rows between `last_time` it ran and the `current_time`, set `last_time` to `current_time`, and repeat in a while loop.

Comment: The code snippet you have provided is not for Spark Structured Streaming, it is a static read. Streaming uses `readStream`. Please go through the official documentation to understand it in a better way: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to use `delta` table. Like this on Databricks Notebook:

```
data = spark.range(0, 5)
data.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("T1")
stream = spark.readStream.format("delta").table("T1").writeStream.format("console").start()

// In another cell, execute:
data = spark.range(6, 10)
```

In DriverLogs can see 2 sets of data, then.